# Accessing list elements of list() in python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a dataset of the form as follows:

`[list(['Error:% 1', 'त्रुटिः% 1']) list(['behavior', 'चाल-चलन'])]`

I want it in the form as follows:

`[['Error:% 1', 'त्रुटिः% 1']['behavior', 'चाल-चलन']]`

so that I can access all the English data using dataset[:, 0] or something similar to that for above.

Comment: So, you don't want it as a list of lists but as a 2D array??

Comment: yes, for now it gives this error: Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-92-a5a3ff339a70>", line 1, in <module>
    print(dataset[0:, 0])

IndexError: too many indices for array

Comment: Why are you using `numpy` here?

Comment: then what to use?

Comment: can someone give me a sytax to print only the english sentences in the above data with list of lists?

Comment: If it's a list of list then you can easily do this:
`some_list=[list(['Error:% 1', 'त्रुटिः% 1']) ,list(['behavior', 'चाल-चलन'])]
print(some_list)
for i in some_list:
    print(i[0])`
`# Error:% 1
behavior`

Answer (score 2):

You have to use a numpy structured array to be able to use compound indexes.

```
x = numpy.array( [("one", "two"), ("four", "five")])
print(x[:, 0])
```

> ['one', 'four']

In your example you have a list of lists, so you could only use single index.

```
col0 = [row[0] for row in data]
```

For your specific example.

```
y = [list(['Error:% 1', 'त्रुटिः% 1']), list(['behavior', 'चाल-चलन'])]
x = numpy.array(y)
```

Now x can be accessed using numpy based indicies. (note I added a ',').

```
print(x[:, 0])
```

or non-numpy.

```
print( [ row[0] for row in y ] )
```

Comment: Upvote for using a numpy structured array.  Learn something new every day!

Answer (score 0):

You don't need `list()` (or numpy) at all in this example

This is perfectly valid Python

```
my_list = [ 
  ['Error:% 1', 'त्रुटिः% 1'], 
  ['behavior', 'चाल-चलन'] 
]
```

You access the outer and inner lists as any other

```
>>> print(my_list[1][1])
'चाल-चलन'
```